# Python - construct set with for loop

Tags: python

Saw this code on leetcode and don't get what it does or how it works. Paths is a list of lists.

```
def solution(paths):
    s = set(p[0] for p in paths)
```

Comment: it's a function that take an 2-D array(arrays inside an array), then second line loop through 2-D array and take first element of the Nested array and store it in a set which is like an unordered list where elements can't be repeated then return final set

Answer (score 2):

Ok not sure which part of the code you were referring to.

```
def solution(**paths**):          #1
    s = set(p[0] for p in paths)  #2
```

#1 creates a function called solution, that takes one argument (path)

#2 assigns a set to the variable **s**.

**set( )** is a function creates a set object.

**p[0]** is the item you want from the forloop. and you are grabbing the **first variable** in each **set** that is in path

it can also be interpeted as:

```
def solution(paths):
    s = {}           # declare variable
    for item in path: # use forloop
        s.add(item[0]) #add the first element of each item in path (the set in path)
    print(s)

test_path = [ ['a','b','c'] , ['a','e','f'], ['g','h','i'] ]
solution(test_path)
```

notice in the results printed below that only one of the 'a' is added because a set only has unique variables

```
>>>{'g', 'a'}
```

You can do some Research on list comprehensions.
I only started learning Python a few months ago myself.
but i found this great video that I think explains the different types of comprehensions very well.

[Python Tutorial: Comprehensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dt4OGnU5sM&t=954s)

Answer (score 0):

p is a list, and p[0] takes the first item in the sub-list, and this gets added to a set (i.e., duplicates are removed).

For example, if `paths = [[1,2,3] , [1,3,4], [2,3,4]]`

```
s = {1, 2}
```

Note that function doesn't return anything since it does not have 'return'.